# What is the exact order of UITableViewDelegate Methods - Strange behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, delegates

Im doing some research to get tableview delegate methods exact order of execution.

### Case 1: Number of rows - For small values

So firstly I have created `100` rows and found the execution flow as below.

> 1. numberOfSectionsInTableView
> 2. numberOfRowsInSection
> 3. cellForRowAtIndexPath

### Case 2: Number of rows - Above Int limit

I tried returning value greater than int limit

Then found an exception thrown. Works great.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
 reason: 'Failed to allocate data stores for 402337200000000 rows in section 0.
 Consider using fewer rows'
```

### Case 3: Number of rows - Int value but higher

After that I changed the number of rows to `4023372000000` an ideal value but confirms to the return type Int.

At that time it takes more than 5 minutes and any of the delegate method was getting called after it gotta crashed. stuck before cellForRowAt getting called. Also my system got stucked for that much time. No logs on crash.

memory usage during stuck

**Memory usage goes high**

free space= -50GB(using my system memory too) 
Percentage usage = 600%

If they are sure it is gonna crash then this range should be included in Exception case.

Did they doing something else during that time?

**In case 3 the compiler is doing something else and the concept "Only cells that is to be displayed in screen will be loaded for tableview" is failing.**

Comment: Its just the CPU which stuck in loading such number of cells in the table view and caused crash and hanged system. i also had failed system crash issue due to an infinite loop in my code. So, there is no problem with the table view delegate and datasource methods.

Comment: cells will be loaded according to the space available in screen right. So why CPU goes high then

Comment: @Saranjith are you reusing cells ?

Comment: @TusharSharma yes reusingcell with identifier

Comment: Yes, cell will be loaded as per screen size but the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method will get called n times(n= numberOfrowsinSection). Have a breakpoint and check.

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla No cellForRowAtIndexPath will get called in 3rd condition

Comment: Use breakpoint in "numberOfRowsInSection" method. it also get called n times (n= numberOfrowsinSection). It getting crashed in this method thats why cellForRowAtIndexpath not being called.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @pbasdf pls see my edit

Comment: How is the cell looking? I mean can all 100 fit in one screen?  :) ( even so it should not crash but I am curios) .

Comment: 5 of my cells fits on screen.

Answer (score 6):

The title of your question, "What is the exact order of UITableViewDelegate methods", presumes there is a defined order.  The methods you identify:

- numberOfSectionsInTableView:
- numberOfRowsInSection:
- cellForRowAt:

are in fact defined in the [UITableViewDataSource protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource) which makes no mention of the order in which the methods are called.  There seems to be a "logical" order, which is broadly what you observe in your **Case 1**.  However, there are exceptions to this: in my testing, `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` gets called twice in succession, without the other methods being called in between.

In your **Case 2** you specify a huge number of rows, and the tableView therefore throws an exception.  This seems understandable: the tableView is unable to "allocate data stores" for all those rows.  If it is storing even 1 bit of information for each row, that's 46 Terabytes.  Not really surprising it throws an exception.

Your **Case 3** is obviously middle ground.  Why no immediate exception?  Who knows.  The space requirement would be 468 Gigabytes, so far more than any current device, but within the bounds of credibility for a few years hence.  Given that iOS runs on numerous different devices with different memory sizes, some 32bit, some 64bit, etc, the Apple Developers can't, for any given number of rows, be "sure it's gonna crash".  So plainly they've decided/defaulted to trying.

So what is happening after calling `numberOfRowsInSection` and before calling `cellForRowAt` (or crashing)?  The tableView is obviously doing something to try to fulfil the request for those rows.

The [UITableViewDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate) defines several methods under the heading "Configuring Rows for the Table View":

- heightForRowAt:
- estimatedHeightForRowAt:
- indentationLevelForRowAt:
- willDisplay:forRowAt:
- shouldSpringLoadRowAt:with:

These are all optional methods, but implementing them might give some clue as to what's going on.  From what I can see, `heightForRowAt` is called after `cellForRowAt` (so only when a cell has been allocated to a particular row).  But it looks like `estimatedHeightForRowAt` is called separately for each and every row, after `numberOfRowsInSection` and before `cellForRowAt`.

Why should the tableView want to know the estimated height of all the rows, before loading a cell for even one of them?  My guess is that the tableView is trying to determine its overall `contentSize`: adding up the heights of all the rows to get the total height.  Implementing `estimatedHeightForRowAt` is obviously adding to the tableView's work and so slowing it down, but even if you have not implemented that method, the tableView must be doing something to calculate the height of each and every row: that takes time and memory.

Turning to your conclusion, "the concept 'Only cells that is to be displayed in screen will be loaded for tableview' is failing": note that the memory being used and the time taken is related to the number of *rows*, NOT the number of *cells*.  The method names all refer to `...*row*At`.  Even the exception in **Case 2** refers to the data stores for *rows*.  If you log `cellForRowAt` you will see that it is called only for as many rows as are on screen, give or take a couple, until you scroll.  Scrolling causes cells to go off screen, at which point the tableView puts them in its queue ready to be reused ("dequeued") for a row about to appear on screen.  So your conclusion is wrong: cells **are** only loaded for rows appearing on screen.